# Interface Inhertiance - override documenation

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

In my project I have an interface called `PullImportSource` which specifies the method `startImport(string)` this method has a general documentation on what methods that implement this method do. However, I have another interface called `ServerImportSource` which is a subtype of `PullImportSource`. I would now like to override the documentation of the inherited member for implementations of subtypes of `ServerImportSource`. I am using XML documentation. The only way I see so far is hiding the inherited member and redocument. But this does not seem like the right to do.
Thus, I would be glad for any feedback
thanks in advance
j

Comment: Please post a [mcve].